# Big/Popular javascript library github projects: why so many tiny files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In several of the standard/popular javascript libraries, like [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) and [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/src), there are *many* very tiny files that are built up to make the final library file, in many cases the files are just a few lines long.

I am not sure I appreciate the reason for the degree to which this partitioning occurs. It would seem to make navigating/comprehending the code base much tougher. Note that I realize that jQuery breaks some things up to allow custom builds with just specified modules, but there are still many tiny files within those module directories.

I was thinking it might be for unit testing purposes, but it looks like a lot of the files don't have anything in them that could be tested in isolation.

Comment: The files are separated by functionality - akin to how Classes would be structured in any true OOP language.

Comment: In addition to the point about seperation of functionality, you've also got to remember that these are open source project and could have thousands of contributions. having them split up in this way reduces a lot of merge issues

Comment: I don't think merging is really any different since git stores data based on content, not file boundaries. The file structure doesn't really change anything. If you touch the same code you might have issues regardless of which file or files the code lives in.

Comment: I meant more if you have a file that a large number of people wanted to contribute on, having many possibily related pull request on the same file might get frustrating from the point of the project owner rather then in a technical sense. Sadly my github projects never get pull requests so I dont have the issue

Answer (score 0):

This really just comes down to personal preference.  With javascript, it all just gets concatenated and minified anyways, so it really doesn't matter what the file structure looks like. The file structures you see are what the owners/maintainers think makes the most sense for that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting large libraries like these allow the developers to write decoupled, modular code split up into related functionalities. It also helps with merging in contributions from a large number of people (great for open source software)

here are some worthwile resources

Writing module of javascript code, use [require (amd)](http://requirejs.org/)

Wiki page on coupled code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)

Wiki page on modular programming [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Comment: Yes, I get the functionality breakdown/organization (and it's going to be combined/minified as part of the build, anyway) - that's not what I meant to be asking about.  It still seems like the partitioning is commonly done to an extent that in many cases leads to files that are not modules (e.g., using the module pattern) but just a few lines, with little context.   The point about working with merges from many different contributors is interesting.

Comment: I do agree that some times some people who are more accustomed to languages like java, will break up javascript files to mimic things like data classes and dao's which might make sense in java but not so much in javascript. This IMHO is much more obviouls when its a frontend/dom/event style library. This is where I so most of the small, single line, contextless files